# Handle connection breakages in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, database-connection

I have a module written in ruby which connects to a postgres table and then applies some logic and code.

Below is a sample code:

```
module SampleModuleHelper
  def self.traverse_database
     ProductTable.where(:column => value).find_each do |product|
        #some logic here that takes a long time
     end
  end
end
```

ProductTable has more than 3 million records. I have used the where clause to shorten number of records retrieved.

However I need to make the code connection proof. There are times when the connection breaks and I have to start traversing the table from the very beginning. I don't want this, rather it should start where it left off since the time taken is too much for each record.

What is the best way to make the code start where it left off?

One way is to make a table in the database that records the primary key(id) where it stopped and start from there again. But I don't want to make tables in the database as there are many such processes.

Answer (score 2):

You could keep a counter of processed records and use the [`offset`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-offset) method to continue processing.

Something along the lines of:

```
MAX_RETRIES = 3
def self.traverse(query)
  counter = 0
  retries = 0
  begin
    query.offset(counter).find_each do |record| 
      yield record
      counter += 1
    end
  rescue ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished => e # or whatever error you're expecting
    retries += 1
    retry unless retries > MAX_RETRIES
    raise
  end
end

def self.traverse_products
  traverse(ProductTable.where(column: value)) do |product|
    # do something with `product`
  end
end
```

Comment: but how does this function resume from the same point if I start the function again? every time traverse_products is called, counter and retries are initialized to zero.

Comment: You don't need to start it again because it will `retry` any errors by itself. You'll just need to plug in the correct error class because I wasn't sure what kind of error you're expecting to be raised...

Comment: this is great...but I don't think will serve my purpose. I need to run a function in cron task and I want it to run from where it stopped the previous day.

Comment: I don't think I follow... is it supposed to stop in between? Why only resume work the next day and not process everything in one go? Isn't there a good chance that new data has been added or existing data changed in the meantime? Wouldn't it make sense to think about distributing the work across more machines so it gets done in a more timely fashion? What other tools are available? If you want to carry state across application restarts, you'll need to keep it _somewhere_. A counter in Redis maybe?

Comment: Updating in database was always an option. I posted this question to find out if it could be done from within ruby itself. For example, keeping a variable inside module that is a constant for a single run of the program and gets updated every time the program stops or ends. Then when the program has to be started next time, it reads the value of this variable and then restarts. Is it possible to update a variable (a constant) during run time and store it within the same script.

Comment: Of course it is possible but _highly_ inadvisable. It restricts your program to being run from the exact same copy of the script that you modified. If you want to deploy an updated version, run the program from another machine (cloud instance) or a number of other day-to-day things, you'd lose the state. Thus, an external system is required. Redis comes to mind because it's `INCR` command is atomic and thus not prone to race conditions. Good support libraries for Ruby like `RedisClassy` exist to work with it comfortably, too.